Mixed Effects CFA using R and lavaan
I want to conduct a CFA with 3 factors and 9 items each. The data contains cluster of highly varying size. (1 < n < 40, 90 clusters in total while 40 clusters only have one observation). I somehow want to take the cluster structure into account. Common methods like the estimation of robust standard errors will probably not work because of the low number of observations in clusters. I was thinking about specifying a mixed effects model. So far I found no way to implement this in R. Any tips or ideas on how this could be achieved ?

Greetings! When you say you have clusters and want a mixed effects-style model, are you stating that you have repeated measurements? I would provide some more detail in your question about what you are asking for, as it isn't immediately clear to me what the solution may be.

The data comes from an online survey that was conducted on a national level. The unit of observations are students. It also includes information on universities of these students. I would assume that students are nested in universities.
The questionnaire tries to replicate a know factor structure and I want to validate this factor structure using CFA. By ignoring the nested structure of the data, i might violate the assumption of iid standard errors, because I would assume that error terms of students of the same university are correlated. I hope this helped to clarify.

Thanks for clarifying. As far as it is my understanding, having some groups with one observation isn't necessarily a problem of its own, particularly when you have many other clusters that have a lot of units. I've never had this experience myself, but the only issue I foresee is that you have almost half of your clusters containing one observation, which may potentially limit the level of variation possible and be problematic. Mixed effects are doable in lavaan, and example models can be found here.

Multilevel CFA with < 100 clusters typically does not work well (or not at all). See
Hox, J. J., & Maas, C. J. (2001). The accuracy of multilevel structural equation modeling with pseudobalanced groups and small samples. Structural Equation Modeling, 8, 157–174.
Using robust estimation methods (and single-level CFA) may be your only viable option.
